# 'POST' not supported spring mvc - filter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a simple log in page with filter. When I call `/login` I get `POST not Supported` error.

Servlet:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(HttpServletRequest request) {
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Filter

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "loginFilter", urlPatterns = "/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
     HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
     HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
     if (session == null
            || session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/").forward(request, response);
     } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, response);
     }
 }
}
```

Error:

```
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: What will happen in your filter when try to login, do you think?

Comment: what's the name of the login html file? Is it by any change login.html? Change it to loginUser.html for example or modify the request mapping to /loginUser. There should not be a html file and a request mapping with the same name.